# Can you prove that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable using the Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

I have been studying measure theory from the ground up, and am quite excited by the seeming power it holds. I thought of this last evening, and I wish to ask if the following proof of uncountability is fully rigorous:

Note: In the lecture notes I have been reading, to develop the measure-theoretic tools I use in this proof, the uncountability of $\Bbb R$ was not used, so I believe this avoids circular reasoning.

> Any countable subset $Q$ of $\Bbb R$ admits an enumeration of points $\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, i.e. that $x\in Q\iff\exists n\in\Bbb N:q_n=x$, and $q_n=q_m\iff n=m$, by definition of countability. The Lebesgue outer measure $\mu^*$ is defined as the infimum of the volume of countable rectangular covers of that set; taking some arbitrary $\varepsilon\gt0$, one can construct the cover of "rectangles" $R_n=[q_n-\varepsilon\cdot2^{-(1+n)},q_n+\varepsilon\cdot2^{-(1+n)}]$. By construction, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}R_n\supseteq Q$, and $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\mu(R_n)=\varepsilon$ from the geometric series. The outer measure is defined with the infimum of covers, so $\mu^*(Q)\le\varepsilon$ as $\{R_n\}$ is a valid countable cover of $Q$. It follows from $\varepsilon$ as arbitrary that $\mu^*(Q)=0$, and also that $\mu(Q)=0$ - null sets w.r.t the outer measure are Lebesgue measurable. Now take any non-trivial closed interval $[a,b]$ in $\Bbb R$; as it is a "rectangle", it has Lebesgue measure $|b-a|\neq0$, (by definition of the outer measure, right?) Thus any closed interval in $\Bbb R$ cannot be countable, as otherwise it would have null measure (furthermore it cannot be reached as a countable limit of countable sets, since the measure is $\sigma$-additive and the set would still have $0$ measure). Thus the reals are uncountable, and this argument generalises easily to $\Bbb R^n,\Bbb C^n$.

Is this rigorously sufficient as a proof? It feels like cheating somehow, but I can't place my finger on why I feel that, and I certainly can't see any mistakes or circular reasoning.

Comment: Clever. I see no flaw in the argument, but can understand your concern.

Comment: The fact that the measure of an interval is not zero requires a proof.

Comment: @markvs It was taken as axiom, or as a definition in the outer measure being the sum of volumes, where the volume of the primitive object, the rectangle, was defined as $|b-a|\neq0$

Comment: This is the standard method.

Comment: Alright. Then the proof that the measure exists needs a proof.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set    "Every finite or countably infinite subset of the real numbers is a null set. For example, the set of natural numbers and the set of rational numbers are both countably infinite and therefore are null sets when considered as subsets of the real numbers. "    "The empty set is always a null set. More generally, any countable union of null sets is null. Any measurable subset of a null set is itself a null set. "

Comment: If you write everything up completely, you get a much more complicated proof than Cantor's (if any).

Comment: @WillJagy The standard method? That’s interesting. I always thought Cantor’s argument (which I wholeheartedly understand and accept) was the canonical proof. I thought I was just playing around with this when I thought of it

Comment: Perhaps I should say that this is what I remember from 44 years ago, from Royden, where the proof that it really is a measure took us much longer...  https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you very much for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You claim that $\mu^*([a, b]) = b - a$. But this is not obvious from the definition of $\mu^*$: For $S \in 2^{\mathbb{R}}$,
$$\mu^*(S) = \inf\{\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}L(I_j) : I_j \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ are intervals }, \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty}I_j \supset S\}.$$
From the above definition we get $\mu^*([a, b]) \leq L([a, b]) = b - a$ since $[a, b] \supset [a, b]$. The hard part is proving $\mu^*([a, b]) \geq b - a$. This requires special property of $\mathbb{R}$ because if you define an analogous outer measure $\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}^*$ on subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$, the result doesn't hold.

For $S \in 2^{\mathbb{Q}}$, define
$$\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}^*(S) = \inf\{\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}L(I_j) : I_j \subset \mathbb{Q} \text{ are intervals }, \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty}I_j \supset S\}.$$
The same argument that shows $\mu^*(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ shows that $\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}^*(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$. Hence $\mu_{\mathbb{Q}}^*(I) = 0$ for any interval $I \subset \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is it not evident from the fact that any theoretical cover with net length less than $b-a$ can be made disjoint, and the union could, with some translation, form another interval of lesser length, and thus it cannot cover? I can’t see how one would need to argue that an interval cannot be covered by a smaller interval. At least, it is surely evident that $\mu*([0,1])\gt0$, no?

Comment: Perhaps if you could show me how it doesn’t hold for some $\mu_{\Bbb Q}^*$ that would help

Comment: @FShrike I added details about $\mu^*_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: Is [this](https://planetmath.org/proofthattheouterlebesguemeasureofanintervalisitslength) satisfactory?

Comment: @FShrike Yes it is.